# Identify this [Molex Minifit Jr] low voltage electrical connector for lighting

Tags: identification

On the other end of the wires from this connector is a MR16/GU5.3 Socket with Retaining Clips for a bulb.

[image]

My clips need to be replaced so I am looking to replace the entire part with both connectors. But, I cannot identify this clip plug. The male components are exactly 9mm long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a [Molex Mini-Fit Jr](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/039013022_sd.pdf) Connector.  You can compare the dimensions from the linked drawing and/or the picture below.

[image: connector picture]

Comment: good find...  https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=39-01-3028  https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=39-01-3022 next the crimp contacts

Comment: almost same, D shell for each socket is different on one to avoid patent suits so it could be an Asian clone.... and if he needed 10kpcs I used to get this sort of thing.

Comment: crj11, thank you for lending me your brain for a cycle!

Answer (score 2):

It is something like the Molex MLX™ Connectors.

But since you are replacing the 12V lamp and connector, it might be easier to replace both connectors (Plug and socket) using standard connectors that are easier to locate.  e.g. 4 pin Molex HDD plugs used in PC's are easy to shop for in pairs.

This part is usually specified by the shell , the crimp pins and the crimping tool and there is not indication you are aware of this.

Unless you need 10k pcs, .  [good luck finding stock.](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/connectors-interconnects/blade-type-power-connectors-housings/419?k=&pkeyword=&FV=ffe001a3&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the one I am currently working on. That is a Molex MiniFit-Jr 5566 series plug. It is the mate for my header; the one you see on the PCB view.[image: Mate For your Plug]

Also attached is another screen-shot with data for your Molex plug.[image: Your Molex Plug]